# Laravel AJAX showing searched records in Table

Tags: ajax, laravel

when i type something in search box, on key up i am getting all results in ul Tag, i want to show same result in table row instead of ul,

**Ajax Code:**

```
<script>
        $(function(){
    var $datasearch=$('#datasearch');
    $('#searchname').on('keyup', function(){
        $.get('/teachers/search/'+$(this).val(), function(teachers){
            $datasearch.empty();
            for (var i=0; i<teachers.length; i++){

                $datasearch.append('<li>'+teachers[i].efirst+' <a href="/teachers/edit/'+teachers[i].id+'">edit</a></li>');
            }
        });
    });
});
    </script>
```

**view:**

```
<ul id="datasearch"></ul> //how can i replace it with table column one [name] and column two button for each record.
```

**Controller:**

```
public function ajaxsearch(string $value = null){

    return $value ? Teacher::select('id','efirst')->whereRaw("UPPER(efirst) LIKE '".strtoupper($value)."%'")->offset(0)->limit(10)->get() : [];
}
```

PS: i don't want to use append in ajax if possible, if there is simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

The best choice is to use DataTables Plugin!
Other way, is to return HTML directly from a server.

Comment: i don't want to use any plugin.

Comment: Other way, is to return HTML directly from a server. After yo just append via domObject.append(contentThatReturned)

Comment: i am returning json data from server.

Comment: PS: i don't want to use append in ajax if possible, if there is simpler way. If you wanna solve it simple way, return HTML to ajax, and just append iT!